# Boolean expression for sum bit of full adder

Tags: logic

The Boolean expression I find on the internet for the sum bit of a full adder is A xor B xor Cin. Does't this expression exclude the A=1,B=1,Cin=1 situation? When that happens, the sum bit is also 1, isn't it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Like additions, A xor B xor C = (A xor B) xor C = A xor (B xor C)

Answer (score 1):

1 xor 1 xor 1 = 1, so this is correct in that case as well.